# Puede bajar la precisión del GPS cuando la batería esta baja

Tags: android, gps

Si una aplicación fue desarrollada para android anterior a 7.1.1 ¿es posible que cuando el nivel de batería es bajo comience a capturar las coordenadas con menor precisión o de forma incorrecta?

¿El modo de captura que se establece en la configuración de android para la ubicación (precisión alta, ahorro de batería, solo dispositivo) queda fija sin importar el nivel de bateria del telefono?

Gracias de antemano, saludos

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas.

Comment: como en opiniones? osea yo realmente necesito saber si eso es posible o si por el contrario la unica forma de que la preciosion cambie es un motivo externo

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, es importante revisar[ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio. Para este tipo de preguntas, trata de obtener reputación para consultar en [chat], saludos,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer las versiones anteriores a Android 8 no contienen condiciones especiales para la optimizacion del uso de bateria en segundo plano.

> A fin de reducir el consumo de energía, Android 8.0 (nivel de API 26) limita la frecuencia con la cual las apps que se ejecutan en segundo plano pueden obtener la ubicación actual del usuario. Las apps pueden recibir actualizaciones de ubicación solo unas pocas veces por hora.

> En casos de uso en segundo plano, es una buena idea limitar las actualizaciones de ubicación. Los límites de Android 8.0 imponen esta práctica, pero las apps que se ejecutan en dispositivos más antiguos deben esforzarse por limitar la ubicación en segundo plano tanto como sea posible.

Con respecto al primer plano:

> Si una app se encuentra en primer plano en un dispositivo que ejecuta Android 8.0 (nivel de API 26), el comportamiento de actualización de la ubicación es el mismo que en Android 7.1.1 (nivel de API 25) y versiones anteriores.

Por lo que la configuracin de frecuencia y precisión quedan a disposición del programador.

En los [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/battery?hl=es-419) hay mas información sobre el uso de batería para las caracteristicas de geolocalizacion. Con respecto al uso de permisos  puedes ver [Location permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions?hl=es-419).